# How can you specify Oracle SQL functions such as trunc() in Rails select functions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the below query written in a Rails controller which is querying an existing Oracle DB and it works fine.

```
    @total_sales_volume = PaymentTransaction.joins(:settlement)
    @total_sales_volume = @total_sales_volume.where("payment_transaction.transaction_status = 'S'
  and payment_settlement.settlement_type = 'D' 
  and trunc(payment_settlement.transaction_date) > sysdate - 30")
```

However, I want to apply Oracle's `trunc()` function on the `payment_settlement.transaction_date` column. So I modified the above query and tried this:

```
@total_sales_volume = PaymentTransaction.joins(:settlement)
@total_sales_volume = @total_sales_volume.where("payment_transaction.transaction_status = 'S'
 and payment_settlement.settlement_type = 'D' 
 and trunc(payment_settlement.transaction_date) > sysdate - 30").select("trunc(payment_settlement.transaction_date), payment_transaction.transaction_amount")
```

But no luck :( as I do not see any change in the actual query that gets fired. Here is the actual query that gets fired to Oracle (found it from the rails server logs)

```
SELECT 
   SUM("PAYMENT_TRANSACTION"."TRANSACTION_AMOUNT") AS sum_transaction_amount,    transaction_date AS transaction_date 
FROM 
"PAYMENT_TRANSACTION" INNER JOIN "PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT" ON "PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT"."PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_ID" = "PAYMENT_TRANSACTION"."PAYMENT_TRANSACTION_ID" 
WHERE 
        (payment_transaction.transaction_status = 'S'
         and payment_settlement.settlement_type = 'D'
         and trunc(payment_settlement.transaction_date) > sysdate - 30) 
        GROUP BY 
         transaction_date
```

Is applying Oracle SQL functions such as `trunc()` supported in ActiveRecord `select` functions?

Comment: What does "no luck" mean - what happens? Do you get an error? Maybe you just need to specify a column alias.

Comment: Updated my above question to answer your question. I do not see any error but I also do not any change in the SQL query that gets fired to Oracle